# Django templates - if statement before displaying a {% block %} tag not working properly?

Tags: django, inheritance, django-templates

This is my basic html page which my other html pages extend off of (it is called base.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Django Bookmarks | {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/site_media/css/style.css' />
    </head>

    <body>

        {% block header %}
            <p> signed in! </p>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    </body>

</html>
```

Now, this is my main page.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Title {% endblock %}

{% if user.username %}
{% else %}
    {% block header %}{% endblock %}
{% endif %}

{% block content %}
    {% if user.username  %}
        <p>Welcome {{ user.username }}.</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Not Signed in</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

as you can see, I want my

```
{% block header %}{% endblock %}
```

to be empty if no user is signed in, but if there is a user signed in, I want the

```
{% block header %}
```

to inherit from base.html. However, it does not inherit from base.html even when a user is signed in. The header block does not show when the user is signed in. Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `block.super`:

```
{% block header %}
    {% if user.username %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% else %}
        {# empty #}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

According to [Django template documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/templates/):

> If you need to get the content of the block from the parent template,
>   the `{{ block.super }}` variable will do the trick. This is useful if
>   you want to add to the contents of a parent block instead of
>   completely overriding it. .....